# select all records created within the hour

Tags: mysql, database

```
startTimestamp < date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 hour)
```

Will the (sub)query above return all records created within the hour? If not will someone please show me a correct one? The complete query may look as follows:

```
select * from table where startTimestamp < date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 hour);
```

Answer (score 19):

Rather than `CURDATE()`, use `NOW()` and use `>=` rather than `<` since you want timestamps to be greater than the timestamp from one hour ago.  `CURDATE()` returns only the date portion, where `NOW()` returns both date and time.

```
startTimestamp >= date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour)
```

For example, in my timezone it is 12:28

```
SELECT NOW(), date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour);
2011-09-13 12:28:53  2011-09-13 11:28:53
```

All together, what you need is:

```
select * from table where startTimestamp >= date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour);
```

Comment: how to substract it so that from 12:28:53 i get 11:00:00 ?

Comment: may i select from all tables of a single database?

Comment: @mario With a `UNION` query separately including each table, but you can't usually `SELECT *` with a `UNION` because the tables have different columns.